# Can I use Boto3 to automatically generate visualization from Athena to QuickSight?

Tags: python, boto3, visualization, amazon-athena, amazon-quicksight

Right now using Boto3 to run Python script to automate Athena queries. After getting the output, can I also use Boto3 to run another Python script and have the output populated in a specific dashboard template?

Non-technical, not sure about feasibility. Just need a simply Y/N answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you need QuickSight to do?
If you need to ingest new data so that existing dashboard starts showing new data, you can use CreateIngestion API from here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/APIReference/qs-data.html

If you need to automate QuickSight dashboard creation, see https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-quicksight-api-capabilities-to-accelerate-your-bi-transformation/